# lftp run jar file after mirror has changed files?

Tags: bash, ftp

I want to sync an ftp directory with `lftp`, and run a jar file afterwards, but only if any files have been changed.

For testing, I just tried to execute another bash file after sync has finished, but it does not work:

lftp.sh:

```
lftp -f "
open $HOST
user $USER $PASS
lcd $SOURCEFOLDER
mirror --delete --verbose --on-change=test.sh $SOURCEFOLDER $TARGETFOLDER
bye
"
```

test.sh:

```
echo test ok
```

Result:

> Unknown command `test.sh'.

Why, and how can I improve this?
Absolute path also fails!

If not possible, how can I catch some kind of status code on exit to determine if there was a change on sync, and execute a command in case?

As well it would be fine if I could just get the number of *new* files transfered.

Comment: Is `test.sh` in `PATH`? If not, specify the full path to the script.

Comment: No, it's a script that lies in the same path as the lftp.sh script. But using absolute path gives the same error.

Comment: Change `--on-change=test.sh` to use the absolute path to `test.sh`, ensure `test.sh` is executable, and starts with `#!/bin/bash` (or some valid shell (from `/etc/shells`))

Comment: Both my files start with `#!/bin/bash`. I also tried absolute path which results in the same error. Both files are also executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manuals for lftp realy [states that](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/lftp.1.html):

> --on-change=CMD           execute the command if anything                                             has been changed

But idea is that CMD is lftp command, not Bash. So to execute local script 'task.sh' we should use lftp expression like `source task.sh` or `! task.sh`.

```
SCRIPTFOLDER="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
lftp -c " 
open ${HOST}
user ${USER} ${PASS} 
lcd $LOCALTARGETFOLDER
mirror --delete --verbose --on-change='source $SCRIPTFOLDER/test.sh' $REMOTESOURCEFOLDER $LOCALTARGETFOLDER
bye
"
```

Comment: That works like a charm, and I'm happy to give you the bonus!